# Dividing by Fractions in Algebra

Tags: fractions

You can divide by a fraction by multiplying by its reciprocal (i.e. $\frac{a}{b}\div\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b}\times\frac{d}{c}$). Given the equation $\frac{1}{2}x = 5$, intuitively, you could either multiply both sides by two or divide both sides by $\frac{1}{2}$. Both of these solutions give the same result, $x=10$.

My maths teacher says that, when showing your work, you can only multiply by two. *Subjectively*, this is simpler. Is this an accepted rule, or is it just personal preference?

P.S. One of my previous teachers did teach to divide by fractions in this case.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. Both ways is fine as long as the number you are dividing by in not a zero.

Comment: You could even multiply by 4, and then solve $2x = 20$ by dividing by 2. Or you could multiply by 3 to get $\frac{3}{2} x = 15$, and then subtract off the original equation. Lots of options exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s totally inaccurate. You can definitely divide by fractions. For example,

$$\begin{align}
0.5x &= 5 \\
\frac{0.5x}{0.5} &= \frac{5}{0.5} \\
x &= 10 \\
\end{align}$$

It’s all the same.

I’d also like to add that “don’t divide by fractions” doesn’t make any sense when you have irrational numbers. For example, if $\pi x=2$, how, are you supposed to solve for $x$? You can’t divide by $\pi$ since it’s not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned ("multiplying by its reciprocal"), we can see that multiplying by $2$ ***is*** dividing by $\frac{1}{2}$.

$\dfrac{x}{\frac{1}{2}}=x\cdot\frac{2}{1}=2x$